# Postgres not using index in citext column

Tags: postgresql, index, execution-plan

The following query is returning a SEQ Scan instead a Index.

```
select file_name from myschemadb.my_files where file_name = 'djsaidjasdjoasdjoaidad'
```

**Engine**

Postgres 11.5

**My table:**

```
CREATE TABLE myschemadb.my_files

    id int4 NOT NULL,
    file_name myschemadb.citext NOT NULL,
    status_id int4 NOT NULL,<br />
    file_key myschemadb.citext NOT NULL,
    is_fine bool NOT NULL DEFAULT true,
    create_date timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    update_date timestamptz NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_my_files PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

**The created index:**

```
CREATE INDEX my_files_file_name_idx ON myschemadb.my_files USING btree (file_name);
```

**Execution Plan**

```
[
   {
      "Plan": {
         "Node Type": "Gather",
         "Parallel Aware": false,
         "Startup Cost": 1000,
         "Total Cost": 70105.63,
         "Plan Rows": 1,
         "Plan Width": 41,
         "Actual Startup Time": 109.537,
         "Actual Total Time": 110.638,
         "Actual Rows": 0,
         "Actual Loops": 1,
         "Output": [
            "file_name"
         ],
         "Workers Planned": 2,
         "Workers Launched": 2,
         "Single Copy": false,
         "Shared Hit Blocks": 58326,
         "Shared Read Blocks": 0,
         "Shared Dirtied Blocks": 0,
         "Shared Written Blocks": 0,
         "Local Hit Blocks": 0,
         "Local Read Blocks": 0,
         "Local Dirtied Blocks": 0,
         "Local Written Blocks": 0,
         "Temp Read Blocks": 0,
         "Temp Written Blocks": 0,
         "I/O Read Time": 0,
         "I/O Write Time": 0,
         "Plans": [
            {
               "Node Type": "Seq Scan",
               "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
               "Parallel Aware": true,
               "Relation Name": "my_files",
               "Schema": "myschemadb",
               "Alias": "my_files",
               "Startup Cost": 0,
               "Total Cost": 69105.53,
               "Plan Rows": 1,
               "Plan Width": 41,
               "Actual Startup Time": 107.42,
               "Actual Total Time": 107.42,
               "Actual Rows": 0,
               "Actual Loops": 3,
               "Output": [
                  "file_name"
               ],
               "Filter": "((my_files.file_name)::text = 'djsaidjasdjoasdjoaidad'::text)",
               "Rows Removed by Filter": 690443,
               "Shared Hit Blocks": 58326,
               "Shared Read Blocks": 0,
               "Shared Dirtied Blocks": 0,
               "Shared Written Blocks": 0,
               "Local Hit Blocks": 0,
               "Local Read Blocks": 0,
               "Local Dirtied Blocks": 0,
               "Local Written Blocks": 0,
               "Temp Read Blocks": 0,
               "Temp Written Blocks": 0,
               "I/O Read Time": 0,
               "I/O Write Time": 0,
               "Workers": [
                  {
                     "Worker Number": 0,
                     "Actual Startup Time": 106.121,
                     "Actual Total Time": 106.121,
                     "Actual Rows": 0,
                     "Actual Loops": 1,
                     "Shared Hit Blocks": 15754,
                     "Shared Read Blocks": 0,
                     "Shared Dirtied Blocks": 0,
                     "Shared Written Blocks": 0,
                     "Local Hit Blocks": 0,
                     "Local Read Blocks": 0,
                     "Local Dirtied Blocks": 0,
                     "Local Written Blocks": 0,
                     "Temp Read Blocks": 0,
                     "Temp Written Blocks": 0,
                     "I/O Read Time": 0,
                     "I/O Write Time": 0
                  },
                  {
                     "Worker Number": 1,
                     "Actual Startup Time": 106.821,
                     "Actual Total Time": 106.821,
                     "Actual Rows": 0,
                     "Actual Loops": 1,
                     "Shared Hit Blocks": 26303,
                     "Shared Read Blocks": 0,
                     "Shared Dirtied Blocks": 0,
                     "Shared Written Blocks": 0,
                     "Local Hit Blocks": 0,
                     "Local Read Blocks": 0,
                     "Local Dirtied Blocks": 0,
                     "Local Written Blocks": 0,
                     "Temp Read Blocks": 0,
                     "Temp Written Blocks": 0,
                     "I/O Read Time": 0,
                     "I/O Write Time": 0
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      },
      "Planning Time": 0.034,
      "Triggers": [],
      "Execution Time": 110.652
   }
]
```

I guess the problem is here:

```
"Filter": "((my_files.file_name)::text = 'djsaidjasdjoasdjoaidad'::text)",
```

This implicit conversion can be a problem.
But when i make a explicit conversion doesnt work too:

```
select file_name from myschemadb.file_history where file_name = 'djsaidjasdjoasdjoaidad'::myschemadb.citext
```

I see this link: [Why does a comparison between CITEXT and TEXT fail?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/181912/why-does-a-comparison-between-citext-and-text-fail)

but didn't help me..

Comment: Is `myschemadb` in `search_path`? If not, can you try adding it and see if that makes a difference?

Comment: Did you run 'vacuum analyze' after creating index? Also I recommend pg_trgrm for text searches

Comment: @DanielVérité dont make difference. But help me, because i found that schema was a problem.

Comment: @YavuzSelim yes, i run vacuum analyze, i tried to change random_past_cost parameter, change table statistic, but the solution was alter extension to public schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks you all!

With a Daniel Vérité help, I found the problem.

The citext extension must be created without "schema". When i created i used:

```
CREATE EXTENSION citext WITH SCHEMA myschemadb
```

But the index is used only when citext is on public schema.

So, you can do this:

```
CREATE EXTENSION citext WITH SCHEMA public
```

or this:

```
CREATE EXTENSION citext
```